# TV show or movie about yellow slime

Tags: story-identification

I saw this on TV in the UK, probably in the late 80s.  It was animated, and could have been a movie or TV show.

It featured a yellow slime, which could eat through anything.  I don't recall if it was a chemical ooze or a 'grey goo' nanite swarm.  I think they tried containing it in glass at one point, but it dissolved the glass.

Right at the end, the yellow slime has been defeated, but then one of the characters notices something.

"The yellow slime!"

"Don't worry, it's only mustard."

Although it could have been custard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another trip to the Hollywood Acid page on TV Tropes has finally revealed the answer.

[It Lives! It Grows! It Destroys!](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/xttlr4) is season 1, episode 8 of The Incredible Hulk, an animated TV show from the 1980s.  A rival scientist has created a yellow slime that dissolves everything it touches, which of course immediately escapes.  The hulk defeats it and all is well.  The final scene in the above video is the one I have the vivid memory of, and it did indeed turn out to be mustard.

Comment: I remember that slime from a Hulk comic book.